# How to add class to an other div when radio checked

Tags: radio-button, addclass, checked

I want to add and remove class to other div in the page when radio button is checked... Please guide me how can I do this via jquery or java ... I need a simple solution as I am not good at programming ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do something like this in jQuery:

```
$("#radio-btn-id").click(function(){
    $("#div-id").addClass('desiredClassName1');
    $("#div-id").removeClass('desiredClassName2');
});
```